# In Sitecore, can you give a media library item an alias?

Tags: sitecore

I'd like to upload a PDF to Sitecore's media library and assign it an alias like "example.com/hr/form.pdf".

... rather than "example.com/~media/docs/form.ashx".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign an URL Alias to media items. Well, you can assign them, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

However, you could implement your own `ItemResolver` pipeline processor that adds alias functionality to media items. Combine that with a custom implementation of the `MediaProvider`, so that the links to media items are generated using their aliases.

I'm not sure how deep your Sitecore knowledge goes, so if you need examples on how to do this, just let me know and I can point you to them.

Comment: This is a good idea and actually pretty straightforward.  I recommend adding a new processor to the httpRequestBegin pipeline.  Drop it in just before ItemResolver or FileResolver.

Comment: Actually, you want to put it after the File- and ItemResolver because Sitecore might be able to resolve to item by itself. Only if Sitecore fails, you want to break into the pipeline and look for it yourself.

Comment: Hi Ruud, Would you be able to give me links for working with ItemResolver & MediaProvider? Cheers

Answer (score 2):

One other approach would be to look at the 301 Redirect Module. It allows both hard coded paths mapped to an item, or rewrite patterns.

http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/301_Redirect_module.aspx

Overall, I've been told to avoid aliases.